# Recaptcha en formulario de contacto con Bootstrap 3

Tags: php, javascript, html5, bootstrap, recaptcha

Tengo un formulario de contacto en HTML con Bootstrap 3 y Bootstrap validator mediante js.

Incluí el recaptcha de Google al HTML y al PHP, pero no se como incluirlo dentro del js para sea validado junto con  el resto de los campos del formulario. Cuando intento enviarlo sin marcar la casilla del captcha, arroja la notificación de que fue enviado, pero no lo está enviando.

Si marco la casilla del captcha entonces si realiza el envío.

¿Cómo  puedo incluir el captcha dentro del JS para su validación igual que el resto de los datos? Y que en caso de no estar marcado, realice la notificación al usuario.

Mi HTML:

```
<head>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="seis-cols-izq col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="php/contacto.php" method="post"  id="contact_form">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                            Nombre
                        </label>  
                        <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                <input  name="name" placeholder="Tu nombre" class="form-control"  type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Empresa</label> 
                        <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i></span>
                                <input name="company" placeholder="Tu empresa" class="form-control"  type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label forma">E-Mail</label>  
                        <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                                <input name="email" placeholder="tucorreo@mail.com" class="form-control"  type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Teléfono</label>  
                        <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                                <input name="phone" placeholder="(55)1234-5678" class="form-control" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tu comentario</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                                <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Cuéntanos cómo podemos ayudarte:"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="API_KEY"></div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Success message -->
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message"><span class="bold">¡Listo!</span> Tu mensaje fue enviado, en breve nos pondremos en contacto contigo.</div>

                    <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-12 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-contacto">Enviar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>

        </div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Mi PHP:

```
<?php
$EmailFrom = "contacto@mail.mx";
$EmailTo = "hola@mail.mx";
$Subject = "Nuevo comentario en el website";
$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$company = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['company'])); 
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone'])); 
$comment = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['comment'])); 

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Nombre: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Empresa: ";
$Body .= $company;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "E-mail: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Teléfono: ";
$Body .= $phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Comentario: ";
$Body .= $comment;
$Body .= "\n";

$recaptcha = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = array(
        'secret' => 'API_SECRET',
        'response' => $recaptcha
    );
    $options = array(
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $captcha_success = json_decode($verify);
    if ($captcha_success->success) {
        // No eres un robot, continuamos con el envío del email
        // ...
        // ...
    } else {
        // Eres un robot!
    }

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
    echo "<h2>¡Gracias! Recibimos tu mensaje</h2>";
}
else{
    echo "<h2>Lo sentimos, hubo un error, inténtalo nuevamente</h2>";
}
?>
```

Y mi js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({

        submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
        $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow") // Do something ...
                $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

            var bv = form.data('bootstrapValidator');
            // Use Ajax to submit form data
            $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }, 'json');
        },

        fields: {
            name: {
                validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                        min: 4,
                        message: 'Este campo debe tener al menos 4 caracteres'
                    },
                        notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Por favor, indícanos tu nombre'
                    }
                }
            },
             company: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                        message: 'Este campo debe tener al menos 2 caracteres'
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Por favor, dínos el nombre de tu empresa'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Necesitamos una dirección de correo donde contactarte'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'Tu dirección de correo no es válida'
                    }
                }
            },
            phone: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Por favor, proporciónanos tu teléfono'
                    },
                    phone: {
                        country: 'MX',
                        message: 'Incluye un número de teléfono válido de 10 dígitos'
                    }
                }
            },

            comment: {
                validators: {
                      stringLength: {
                        min: 10,
                        max: 200,
                        message:'Tu comentario debe contener entre 10 y 200 caracteres'
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Por favor, incluye tu comentario'
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    })
});
```

Espero puedan ayudarme con esto, necesito incluir la validación del recaptcha dentro del JS junto con los demás campos del formulario como está actualmente.

Comment: Primero que nada en tu código PHP te hacen falta sentencias para evitar enviar mensajes en blanco, lo otro es muy sencillo.

Comment: De hecho, la validacion se realiza primero en el js y si todo es correcto, entonces dispara el PHP, si se intenta enviar vacío, el js lo evita y no permite el envío

Comment: Pero igual alguien mas puede aprovecharse de eso y enviar correos vacíos, y crearte spam masivo

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada tu código PHP no tiene sentencias para evitar enviar correos vacíos, para lograr evitar eso solo lo harías así:

```
 <?php
    $EmailFrom = "contacto@mail.mx";
    $EmailTo   = "hola@mail.mx";
    $Subject   = "Nuevo comentario en el website";
    $name      = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
    $company   = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['company']));
    $email     = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    $phone     = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone']));
    $comment   = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['comment']));
    $recaptcha = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

    if (!isset($_POST['name']) && empty($_POST['name']) && !isset($_POST['company']) && empty($_POST['company']) && !isset($_POST['email']) && empty($_POST['email']) && !isset($_POST['phone']) && empty($_POST['phone']) && !isset($_POST['comment']) && empty($_POST['comment'])) {
        // si los campos enviados no existe o están vacios
        // mostramos un error interno y evitamos enviar correos vacios
        header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    } else {
        // prepare email body text
        $Body = "";
        $Body .= "Nombre: ";
        $Body .= $name;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Empresa: ";
        $Body .= $company;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "E-mail: ";
        $Body .= $email;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Teléfono: ";
        $Body .= $phone;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Comentario: ";
        $Body .= $comment;
        $Body .= "\n";

        $url             = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $data            = array(
            'secret' => 'API_SECRET',
            'response' => $recaptcha
        );
        $options         = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );
        $context         = stream_context_create($options);
        $verify          = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        $captcha_success = json_decode($verify);
        if ($captcha_success->success) {
            // No eres un robot, continuamos con el envío del email
            // ...
            // ...
        } else {
            // Eres un robot!
        }

        // send email 
        $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

        // redirect to success page 
        if ($success) {
            echo "<h2>¡Gracias! Recibimos tu mensaje</h2>";
        } else {
            echo "<h2>Lo sentimos, hubo un error, inténtalo nuevamente</h2>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Para lo del javascript solo usa este función, solo cambia el nombre del div del recaptcha el cual es "*.invisible-recaptcha*":

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderInvisibleReCaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var renderInvisibleReCaptcha = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; ++i) {
        var form = document.forms[i];
        var holder = form.querySelector('.invisible-recaptcha');
        if (null === holder) continue;
        (function(frm){
            var holderId = grecaptcha.render(holder, {
            'sitekey': 'my-key-here',
            'badge': 'inline',
            'size': 'invisible',
            'callback': function (recaptchaToken) {HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(frm);},
            'expired-callback': function(){grecaptcha.reset(holderId);}
            });
            frm.onsubmit = function (evt){evt.preventDefault();grecaptcha.execute(holderId);};
        })(form);
    }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias. La validación de datos se realiza en el JS, que verifica primero que los campos del formulario esten correctametne llenados antes de disparar la función POST, por lo que no permite el envío en blanco, por ello no hay sentencias en el PHP que lo eviten, porque todo se realiza en el JS. Hay forma de incluir el recaptcha dentro de la validaciión del JS?

Comment: @ManuelCardenasPerez la función callback del código javascript que te mostré válida el recaptcha desde js, enviado el "*response*" osea el campo **$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]** al código PHP